# Textfile to list form?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I would like to read textfiles into list form but extract the position of each character in the textfile to form a numerical/quantitative list.

An example of one textfile (after the numbers is split by a '\t'):

```
   3         ---
   2        /   \
   1       /     \
   0    ---       \   
  -1               \
```

Where the final output would look like:
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1]

Currently I have:

```
    with open("file.txt", "r") as text:
        split_list = []
    for x in text:
        y = list(x.split("\t"))
        split_list.append(y)

    list_numbers = []
    for a in range(len(split_list)):
        for line in split_list:
            if line[1][a] != " ":
                indexes.append(line[0])
    print(indexes)
```

Which gives the output: ['0', '0', '0', '1', '2', '3', '3']

I suspect I'm doing something wrong with the range(len(split_list)) as my ouput correctly reads the first 7 characters but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're using the length of `split_list` (the height of the chart) as the length of each line (the width of the chart) you should really reverse the order of the nested loops so that you can tell the length of the string in the row:

```
indexes = []
with open("file.txt", "r") as text:
    split_list = []
    for x in text:
        y = list(x.split("\t"))
        split_list.append(y)

list_numbers = []
for line in split_list:
    for ch in line[1]:
       if ch != " ":
           indexes.append(line[0])
print(indexes)
```

but then your list won't be in the order you wanted but that can be fixed by remembering the position (with `enumerate()`) and then sorting by the position, i condensed it into 1 loop for convenience too:

```
unordered_indexes = []
with open("file.txt", "r") as text:
    for line in text:
        val,data = line.split("\t")
        for pos,ch in enumerate(data):
            if ch != " " and ch != "\n":
                unordered_indexes.append((val,pos))
unordered_indexes.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
indexes = [i[0] for i in unordered_indexes]
print indexes
```